# Tabs-like behaviour in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone app which I need tabs-like behaviour in. I want to show and hide all the views for each tab accordingly. For two tabs, I place all the views on top of the others and make them hide and show accordingly. But when I have to implement 3rd tab, there are a lot of views which I can't place on each other in Interface Builder.

Can anybody tell me how to make an UI for this scenario?

Edit: could you take a look at [this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ld12h) and see if it makes any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see!  Why not just do it yourself with some creatively placed UIButtons?  So long as they are in fixed positions, make a sort of radio-group like paring of two buttons approximately 50 px apart from each other and then just set their background colors accordingly.  As for the views, they can easily be called to the front with UIView's -bringSubviewToFront: method.

Comment: I have two background images one for mood selected and other for gratitude selected. The problem is that, how to hide all the uiviews for gratitude when mood is selected and vice versa.Secondly how to make views on one each others i.e placing views on same place and hide and show them according. Should I make this UI via Interface Builder or programmatically?